# Android WebView refuse user input & touches

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to open [web site](https://noor.moe.gov.sa/Noor/login.aspx) via my browser , but it refuses user input

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            urlSite = bundle.getString("passed_url");
        }

        _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        _toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        //webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        // enable javascript
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       //webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.equals("about:blank")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();

            }
        });
        if (urlSite != null) {
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.loadUrl(urlSite);
        }

        //webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);


    }
```

**My tries** I tried webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN) but it dosn't work , I tried both code segments below also but they also fail to fix my issue.

I am struggling for long time and cant find the answer, can anyone help me ?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                v.requestFocusFromTouch(); 

            break; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                v.requestFocus();
            } 
            break; 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line :

```
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Please explain, what specifically is wrong with the code in question, and why your proposed solution solves the issue.

Comment: this solves the issue because this method make webview like desktop browser

Comment: `1` Don't answer in comments. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34376816/edit) your answer instead. `2` You forgot to point out the issue in the question. `3` This sounds like it appears to work by coincidence and has other (unwanted) side-effects.